# split a string from a sequence, with regex

Tags: regex, bash

I need a regular expression that matches letters and digits, but doesn't match the sequence "00".

e.g. "hello00world00number001" should match: "hello", "world", "number" and "1".

I tested without success:

```
(?:[\w](?<!00))+
```

Edit: "hello000world0000number000001" must be separated into: "hello0" "world" "number0" and "1"

Comment: How must be seperated next string: hello000world0000number000001?

Comment: Can you just split along "00" instead?

Comment: hello000world0000number000001 must be separated into: "hello0" "world" "number" and "01"

Comment: You might try to `explode` it?

Comment: i can split word using a recursive process, in each of them i try to match ^(.*?00)(.*)
but I was wondering if I could do in a single regular expression.
I'm working with shell scripting (bash)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Input string: `hello000world0000number00000100test00test20`

#### Split

1. Splitting by `00` alone will generate empty matches if a series like `0000` is encountered:
   Output: `hello/0world//number//01/test/test20`
2. To work around this let's enclose 2 zeroes in a group:
   RegEx: `(00)+` - *last uneven `0` in the series goes to the next match* - [live demo](http://www.regex101.com/r/qX1jQ3)
   Output: `hello/0world/number/01/test/test20`
3. Use a negative lookahead:
   RegEx: `(00)+(?!0)` - *keep the first `0` in an uneven series in the first match* - [live demo](http://www.regex101.com/r/rL6gT0)
   Output: `hello0/world/number0/1/test/test20`

#### Match

1. incorrect result for `00` only
2. `/([a-z0-9]+?)(?:(?:00)+|$)/gi` - [live demo](http://www.regex101.com/r/rT8tI1)
3. `/([a-z0-9]+?)(?:(?:00)+(?!0)|$)/gi` - [live demo](http://www.regex101.com/r/iU2sY1)

Comment: My original purpose was to match the words between delimiters, not the delimiter itself.
Although it is possible to split the string, from the position of the delimiters.

Comment: @acs added the matching regexps also

Comment: Thank you all for your time and answers
And thanks a ton @ka! you are a master!!

Answer (score 1):

```
str = "hello00world00number001"
str.split("00")
```

Why would this not work

Comment: I don't believe it fulfills this case `hello000world0000number000001 must be separated into: "hello0" "world" "number" and "01"`, I believe that would result in `"hello", "0world", "number", "01"`

Comment: @rdp The criteria for that result is not at all clear; why is the initial 0 kept in the first odd-numbered run, but the final 0 in the second?

Comment: I don't think @acs has a clear goal of what he actually want the regex to do

Comment: @Josh I am unsure. I was just pointing it out based on acs comment on his OP. But you make a good point.

Comment: I want to use the sequence "00" as delimiter between words. And get it with regular expressions.

Comment: @rdp, I agree: hello000world0000number000001 must be separated into: "hello", "0world", "number", "01"

Comment: @acs there is no real criteria for what you want from the examples

Comment: The header of the post saying "with Regex"

Comment: @Lior, your obviously not paying attention to what is going on, the examples acs is giving are not consistent, and he hasn't provided a clear explanation of what the regex should do, since I just posted a solution (that works for his first case) obviously I am aware that he wants a regex to split a string

Comment: @aaronman What I wanted to accomplish was to use regex to split strings (letters and digits) from a delimiter sequence, for instance double zero.

Comment: @acs my solution splits on "00" and produces the correct result for both of your examples so what is the problem

Comment: @aaronman no problem, I appreciate your help. 
Only that I want to accomplish this result with regex directly, not with split method.

Comment: @aaronman Your solution works! However, acs was seeking a Regex solution for his question, regardless if you think that it can be accomplish by different ways. His reasons stays with him. If you think, that it cannot be solved by Regex, ONLY then you can give a different way of solving it.

Comment: @Lior, split does take a regular expression as an argument which may be the source of my confusion. A regular expression by itself cannot do anything it has to be passed into a function of some sort, so I am confused as to what is being asked for

Answer (score 1):

You can split "hello000world0000number000001" with this pattern:

```
(00)+(?=0?[^0])
```

Comment: My original purpose was to match the words between delimiters, not the delimiter itself.

Comment: @acs: I know, it's reason why I suggest you to split while waiting for something better.